# Cannot get DOM events on component in host component

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component that contains a list of objects named `lines`.  I build a table from those lines using different components based on the line type.  This works perfectly.  Here's a stripped down version of the component:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="line in lines"
        :key="line.key"
        :is="componentForType[line.eventType] || 'LogLine'"
        v-bind="line"
    />
  </table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'DebugLog',
    components: {
      LogLine,
      FormattedLogLine,
      UserDebug,
      Limits  
    },
    data () {
      return {
        lines: [],
        selectedKey: null,
        componentForType: {
          'USER_DEBUG' : 'UserDebug',
          'LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS' : 'Limits',
          'EXCEPTION_THROWN' : 'FormattedLogLine',
          'FATAL_ERROR' : 'FormattedLogLine'
        }

      }
    },
    mounted() {
      // code that loads this.lines
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now I want to be able to click any row of the table, and have the row become "selected", meaning that I want store `line.key` in `this.selectedKey` and use CSS to render that line differently.  But I can't get the events working.  Here's the updated `<template>`; nothing else is changed:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="line in lines"
        :key="line.key"
        :is="componentForType[line.eventType] || 'LogLine'"
        v-bind="line"
        :class="{selected: line.key == selectedKey}"
        @click.capture="selectedKey = line.key"
    />
  </table>
</template>
```

I've added the last 2 properties on the `tr` element - a dynamic class binding and a `click` event handler to set `this.selectedKey` to the active line's key.  But it isn't working.  I replaced the `@click` handler code with `console.log(line.key)` and nothing is logged, which tells me that my `@click` handler is never firing.  I originally wrote it with out the `.capture` modifier, but tried adding the modifier when the original didn't work.

Is vue.js stopping propagation from the child component to the parent?  Can I not bind the `click` event on the `tr` since it `:is` another vue component?  Or is there something else going on?  The examples I've found in the docs are much simpler and I'm not sure they correspond to my situation.  The various child components are not binding any click events.  I'd prefer to handle the event entirely in the parent as shown, since I will have a number of types of child component, and I don't want to have to implement click handlers in each.

**Update**: Looking at my child components, I note that each contains a `tr` tag that must effectively replace the `tr` in the parent template.  For example, my most basic component is `LogLine`, shown here:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>{{timeStamp}}</td>
    <td>{{eventType}}</td>
    <td>{{lineNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{lineData}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'LogLine',
    props: ['timeStamp', 'eventType', 'lineData', 'lineNumber'],
    data: function () {
      return {}
    }
  }
</script>
```

So I'm guessing that the binding in the parent isn't actually binding on the `tr` in the DOM; it's just binding on the Vue component, listening for a `click` event to be sent from the child with `$emit`; and that each child component will need to bind `@click` on its `tr` and emit it to the parent.  Assuming I'm right, is there any shortcut I can use from the parent template to have vue forward the DOM events?  Any other option I'm missing besides binding `click` in every child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piggy-backing off of Jacob's answer here. Since you're essentially attaching an event listener to a dynamic component it expects a custom `click` event. So you have two options here:

1. Listen for the native DOM `click` event within that component (by attaching a `click` event listener to a normal DOM element within the component) and `emit` a custom `click` event to the parent.
2. Use the `.native` modifier [to listen for the native DOM `click` event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) instead of a custom one directly in the parent.

Comment: Accepted this answer as `.native` is exactly what I wanted.  Changing `@click.capture="selectedKey = line.key"` to `@click.native="selectedKey = line.key"` in the parent's `v-for` works and requires no changes to the child components.

Comment: @Jacob You cracked the problem in the first place so thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using an `:is` prop, it's considered a dynamic Vue component, not a DOM element.

Events listener on a Vue component won't be passed down to its DOM element by default. You have to do it manually by going into the component template and add `v-on="$listeners"`.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/am59ojwx/7/

e.g. `<div v-on="$listeners"> ... </div>`

Answer (score 0):

@Jacob Goh's use of `v-on="$listeners"` is simple and allows forwarding of all DOM events in one action, but I wanted to document an approach I tried on my own for completeness.  <strike>I will be switching to Jacob's solution in my component.</strike>  I am now using Husam's `.native` modifier in the parent as it is more suitable to my particular use case.

I was able to make my component work by editing each child component, capturing the `click` event and re-emitting it.  For example:

```
<template>
  <tr @click="$emit('click')">
    <td>{{timeStamp}}</td>
    <td>{{eventType}}</td>
    <td>{{lineNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{lineData}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'LogLine',
    props: ['timeStamp', 'eventType', 'lineData', 'lineNumber'],
    data: function () {
      return {}
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Another option would be to listen for the native DOM event instead using `@click.native`.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim That does exactly what I want - works from the parent with no changes to the child.  Tested and confirmed it works.  If you will post as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I'll post an answer shortly.